# pH sensor showing incorrect measurement after using on acidic solution

Tags: ph, sensor

I recently acquired an electrode pH sensor for a project of mine. After calibrating the sensor I used it on tap water and then lemon water to test their respective pH. After finding the pH of the lemon water, I tried the sensor on distilled water to confirm my calibration once...but the value was coming out to be greater than 7. I tried dipping the sensor in it's provided storage solution (3N KCl) but still there was only a minimal reduction in the error. Can anyone with the knowledge of pH sensors explain the problem I am facing and any way of overcoming this problem so that I can test multiple solutions together without affecting the accuracy.

Comment: Why do you expect distilled water to have pH 7 ? Think twice..... BTW, I assume you performed at least 2 point calibration bracketing the measured pH range.

Comment: At room temperature shouldn't distilled water have a pH of 7 or at least close to 7. In my case the pH value was coming out to be 7.87. That's why I thought that something was wrong. Secondly, I calibrated the pH sensor by following a tutorial provided with it. This was done by shorting it and then adjusting the offset potentiometer until the output value read was 2.5V.

Comment: The point is, distilled water is never just distilled water. And even if it was, it would not be, when you put in the pH probe. True calibration must be done against standard pH solutions, otherwise you do not know if it provides the correct output.

Comment: Another point is that distilled water can get a little acidic due to CO2 absorption. Hard to get high pH unless vials aren't clean. I don't have an easy explanation, too. Follow the instructions carefully and rinse the bulb immediately after use.

Answer (score 0):

The glass electrode used to measure the pH of a solution is aa long tube terminated by a small glass bulb which is the most important (and the only sensitive) part of the electrode. When dipped into an aqueous solution, this bulb gets a potential which is transformed into a pH value by the pHmeter. But in order to work properly, the glass bulb must be covered by a thin layer of a sensitive gel that should not be touched, rubbed or removed. This thin outer layer adsorbs some ions from the solution, provided the solution is not too concentrated. This absorption is reversible. But, if the glass electrode is dipped into concentrated solutions of acids or of bases, the layer is saturated and may be even destroyed, and will not be able to work properly in the future.

If this accident has happened, the electrode is not able to work properly. The gel must be renewed and synthesized again. The only way to do it is to dip the electrode in a 3 molar KCl solution, and wait a couple of days, depending on the concentration of the acid or base. After this operation, the gel layer will be repaired. It must be checked by dipping the electrode in a known pH buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I understood the problem. But just one small thing...In the answer you have mentioned that the gel layer may get destroyed with concentrated solutions of acids or bases. But in my case I was using just a solution of lemon water that was mildly acidic only.

Comment: @Aditi Mittal. You are right. Your trouble is not due to an effect of high acidic concentration. I must admit that I don't see any simple explanation.